# Конфликт bootstrap 4 и angular 4 - некорректно вычисляется высота блоков

Tags: css, bootstrap, angular2, angular4

Как сделать страницу аналогично https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/3-col-portfolio/ с `boostrap 4` и `angular 4`?

Изначально использовались `boostrap 3` и `angular 4`, 
пытался сделать страницу по примеру, в котором используется `bootstrap 4` https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/3-col-portfolio/
https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-3-col-portfolio/

вот мои попытки с моей версией `boostrap 3`
http://jsfiddle.net/96thessa/4/
здесь вроде бы все работает аналогично, но если добавляется `angular`, место под изображение растягивается на высоту всего блока, а текст съезжает.
при использовании `angular` происходит следующее https://i.stack.imgur.com/bX37g.jpg размеры пустой картинки: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsLYH.jpg
вначале блоки отображаются аналогично http://jsfiddle.net/96thessa/4/ 
но через мгновение пустая картинка занимает всю высоту блока и выталкивает текст ниже границы блока.
С `bootstrap 4` ситуация аналогичная.

Страница - компонент `angular`, соответственно, `boostrap` скрипт и стили подгружаются в индексе, а стиль самого компонента содержит правила для классов `card`, `card-img-top` и т.д. На [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) не знаю, как эти все нюансы воспроизвести с учетом `angular`. Возможно, `angular` вносит смуту? Влияет ли порядок загрузки стилей на расчет размера картинки? Или `boostrap` не стоит подключать через `link` и `script` в `html` файле, а лучше каким-то другим способом? Влияет ли `angular` на отображение изображений таким образом? В стилях в инспекторе браузера не увидел ничего дополнительного, что бы могло исказить отображение. Пробовал использовать изображение, не обрамленное ссылкой `a`, результат тот же.

Update: [архив тестовые исходники](http://my-files.ru/macksm)

Update: пока костыльное решение - не показывать несуществующие изображения (`display: none`), но блоки все равно почему-то растягиваются больше, чем нужно, в высоту. Пытался заменить `margin`-ы на `padding`-и, эффект не особо изменился, автоматический расчет высоты блока происходит неверно, я полагаю, проблема не в изображениях, а в самих блоках.

Update: пытаюсь устранить конфликт angular и bootstrap, используя [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started). Выполнил установку `npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`, убрал подключение `bootstrap.min.js` и `jquery.min.js`, оставив только подключение `bootstrap.min.js (4.0.0-beta.2)`. В `app.module.ts` внес изменения:

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';    
...

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
   ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
...
```

Высота блоков по-прежнему рассчитывается некорректно.

[Ссылка на страницу](http://a0169712.xsph.ru.xsph.ru/items)

Update:
добавил стили

```
.h-100[_ngcontent-c3] { height: auto !important; }
.h-100 { height: auto!important; }
.h-100[_ngcontent-c4] { height: auto !important; }
.container[_ngcontent-c3] .card[_ngcontent-c3] { height: auto !important; }
```

и убрал

```
.h-100 { height: 100%!important; }
```

результат:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCKKB.png
Внешние дивы для блоков имеют корректную высоту, но .card сжимается по контенту по высоте, и соседние колонки не выравниваются в итоге по высоте, хотя стиль `height: auto !important;` применяется. Проверял в chrome, firefox. Искомая страница, с которой сделан скриншот [Ссылка на страницу](http://a0169712.xsph.ru.xsph.ru/items)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы не указали стили к классу **.row**

```
.row {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

> Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Обновление 0.0.1:**

На предоставленном [ресурсе](http://a0169712.xsph.ru.xsph.ru/items) возможно поправить верстку внеся вот такие изменения:

> Удалите css код:

```
.h-100[_ngcontent-c3] {
     height: 100% !important; 
}
.h-100 {
     height: 100%!important; 
}
```

*Если нет возможности удалить, замените на height: auto important;*

После для выравнивания вы можете написать:

```
.portfolio-item[_ngcontent-c3] {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    display: flex;
}
```

И если размер картинок будет всегда один сделать вот так:

```
.card.h-100 img {
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

> В итоге вы получите вот такой результат:

Вариант №1 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
*С картинкой но битой ссылкой*

Вариант №2 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
*Полностью без картинки(без тега < img >)*

Comment: спасибо, пропустил) при использовании angular 2 происходит следующее https://imgur.com/9IZ1Jvx

Comment: вначале блоки отображаются аналогично http://jsfiddle.net/96thessa/4/ но через мгновение пустая картинка занимает всю высоту блока и выталкивает текст ниже границы блока

Comment: Может быть что то не так с вашим "angular 2", не могу запустить с  angular 2

Comment: Посмотрите в стилях, возможно где то есть конфликт. Ссылка https://imgur.com/9IZ1Jvx у меня не открывается.

Comment: Есть ли возможность залить на рабочий сервер проект и предоставить ссылку?

Comment: на сервер, к сожалению, вряд ли, могу только предоставить исходники

Comment: Высылайте исходники

Comment: скинул ссылку в посте

Comment: Наверное происходят конфликты между angular и bootstrap.  Полезные ссылки: [angular-ui.github.io](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#%2Fdropdown)  Ссылка - [Похожая проблема](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36738178/combining-angular-material-with-twitter-bootstrap-without-conflicts).  Так же интересно описывает похожую ситуацию [вот тут - ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313990/using-bootstrap-for-angular-and-material-design-for-angular-together/29326397#29326397)

Comment: залил на сервер, вот искомая страница http://a0169712.xsph.ru.xsph.ru/items ftp: хост 141.8.192.98 логин a0169712 пароль enfageguup

Comment: @Emm на сервере все просто, удалите css код: .h-100[_ngcontent-c3] {
     height: 100% !important; 
}
.h-100 {
     height: 100%!important; 
}   Если нет возможности удалить, замените на height: auto important;

Comment: Обновил ответ,  то ли это что вам нужно?

Comment: Удалить вряд ли, я полагаю, эти классы автоматически добавляет ангуляр. Заменил, не помогает, содержимое блоков в пределах блоков остается теперь, но цель сделать одинаковую высоту блоков для выравнивания контента не достигнута

Comment: и то, это при условии скрытия пустых изображений путем добавления onerror = "this.style.display = 'none'", иначе и изображения так же растягиваются в высоту, и высота блоков при этом разная

Comment: почему не помогает  ? Работает же

Comment: Попробуйте обратится к блокам например вот так: .container[_ngcontent-c3] .card[_ngcontent-c3] {
    height: auto !important;
} или что то на подобие

Comment: Попробуйте для теста  добавить стили на ту же страницу где блоки

Comment: стиль `height: auto !important;` применяется, но эффект не тот, что нужен - блоки разной высоты. добавил эти стили на сервер, они вроде как применяются, но .card несмотря на height: auto !important все равно не растягивается на нужную высоту, как соседние, вот скриншот страницы http://a0169712.xsph.ru.xsph.ru/items, размещенной на сервере https://i.imgur.com/ULzNpFK.png Проверял в chrome, firefox

Comment: Увидел обновленный ответ, добавил .portfolio-item[_ngcontent-c3] {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    display: flex;
}  все получилось, спасибо